# Float image outside table in HTML Email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm looking to create a HTML email that should work in all the major email clients. (Read - ugly table-based layouts)

The design looks something like:

[image: this sample image].

I can't use absolute positioning for the image (the circle with thunder) because it's not supported in email clients.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

The EDM needs to be responsive as well as have the rounded corners on the rectangle.

Also the width of the rectangle can't be a fixed width either.

Comment: Do not use absolute positioning, try to slice image (the circle with thunder) and place it

Comment: you can used as img tag if you are using email

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
 .rectangle{
  display:block;
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  background:orange;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:100px;
    border-top-left-radius: .5em;
    border-top-right-radius: .5em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .5em;
}
p
{
  margin-top:38px;
  position:fixed;
  color:white;
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}


.circle{
  position:absolute; 
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-25px;
  top: -40px;

}
.circle img{
  position:absolute;
width: 100px;
 border:3px solid white;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left:50%;
  margin-left:-25px;
  top: -20px;
    }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wx0zb6f8/11/)

Comment: I can't use absolute positioning since it needs to be a table based layout compatible with email clients.

Answer (score 0):

Use an external div for the thunder image.
Then give it a `disply:block` and use the `text-align:center;` to bring it to center

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/gje91rzs/embedded/result/